# Static method loop logic

Tags: c#

I have a static method in a static class that takes 2 int variables (input1 and input2). How can I write it without using switch case so that if input2 is 3

input1 = 0 returns 0

input1 = 1 returns 1

input1 = 2 returns 2

input1 = 3 returns 0

input1 = 4 returns 1

input1 = 5 returns 2

input1 = 6 returns 0

input1 = 7 returns 1

and so on....

And if input2 is 4

input1 = 0 returns 0

input1 = 1 returns 1

input1 = 2 returns 2

input1 = 3 returns 3

input1 = 4 returns 0

input1 = 5 returns 1

input1 = 6 returns 2

input1 = 7 returns 3

input1 = 8 returns 0

and so on...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to have the two inputs related by the [remainder operation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx).

```
public static int logic(int input1, int input2)
{
     return input1 % input2;
}
```

Comment: I believe its called the [Modulo Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) :)

Comment: @SwDevMan81 That is another name for it.  The documentation link I provided calls it "remainder".